# Select row by multiple columns with multiple rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm new to Mysql. In one of my mysql tables, I have a row that two columns involved and I need to list user as multiple rows, I'm wondering if it is possible.

For instance, in mysql table1, there is only one user1 as below;

```
 id      username       value1       value2
 ===========================================
 1       user1          abc           def
```

I want to group user1 by pass1 and pass2 with an additional row as below;

```
 id      username       allvalues     value
 =============================================
 1       user1          value1          abc
 2       user1          value2          def
```

id number is not important at that point as long as it is uniqe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider amending the design of table1 so that it looks more like table2 to begin with. Note that id='2' is rather meaningless in the present context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with UNION

```
select username,'value1' as allvalues, value1 as value from tablename
union
select username,'value2' as allvalues, value2 as value from tablename
```

Comment: thanks. I did not know union is for this purpose. However, id numbers end up with the same as '1' that i need to increase id number +1 for every row.

Answer (score 2):

you could use a UNION

```
select  username, 'value1' allvalues , value1 
from my_table  
union  
select  username, 'value2' , value2
from my_table
```